# How to scrape an infinite load page with R

Tags: javascript, r, web-scraping

I've been scraping some news media pages for my small research. And I've encountered this [page](http://zyme.lrytas.lt/politika) where the articles load as you scroll. I've tried monitoring the response in the `F12` inspector and figured out (with the `XHR` file) that the pages do indeed load separately after a certain number of articles.

I can even see the URLs to them in the inspector, a screenshot to show what I mean,

[image: screenshot]

However, I have no idea how to load this information into `R`. I've been using `Rvest`, but not sure if it's helpful here, perhaps HTTR?

Thank you!

Comment: I would suggest you used RSelenium that imitates web browser activity

Answer (score 0):

You can page through the raw json at this endpoint:

```
http://kolumbus-api.lrytas.lt/query/?count=&tag_slugs=politika&type=Video,Articolo&order=pubfromdate-&ret_fields=props.type__AS__type,props.media[indexof(x.type=%27media%27%20for%20x%20in%20props.media)][%27hd-alternate-href%27]__AS__thumb,props.categories[0].name__AS__category,props.href__AS__href,props.title__AS__title,props.commentCount__AS__commentCount,props.media[indexof(x.type=%27media%27%20for%20x%20in%20props.media)].otheralternate.1280x720.href__AS__imgxl,props.media[indexof(x.type=%27media%27%20for%20x%20in%20props.media)].otheralternate.300x200.href__AS__imgm,props.media__AS__media_json&page=1
```

just page through changing the page parameter at the very end there: `page=1` until you reach the end.